# Copy value of one textbox to another using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i just want to paste the content of one textbox to other when i click the button u . but it is not showing.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery_min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
var ravi=$("#text").val();
 $("$text1").val(ravi);
 });
 });
 </script>

 </head>
  <body>
 <input type="text" value="ravi" id="text">
 <input type="text" id="text1">
 <input type="button" value="u" id="button">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: because you have a syntax error, `$text1` needs to be `#text1`, which you would have seen an error if you looked at the console when running this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `#` to target element by `id` in jQuery, so change:

```
$("$text1").val(ravi);
```

to:

```
$("#text1").val(ravi);
```